# Iterating through an array and checking values of the items

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

I'm populating an array by taking data from a mysql table, and what I'm trying to do is iterate through that array, check the value of each item and then do perform different actions depending on what the value is.

This is the code for the method where I connect to the database and try and iterate through the array

```
public void HomeRecord(){

    ArrayList<HomeTeamResults> allResults = new ArrayList<>();

    try 
    {
        //Sets up the connedtion to the database and installs drivers which are required.

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");                                                                        

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost", "username", "password");   


        String table = box1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE `HomeTeam` = ?";
        PreparedStatement prepst;            

        prepst =  con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        prepst.setString(1,box1.getSelectedItem().toString());
        rs = prepst.executeQuery();

        HomeTeamResults hometeamResults=null;
        while (rs.next()) 
        {               
            hometeam = rs.getString("HomeTeam");                      
            awayteam = rs.getString("AwayTeam");                   
            result = rs.getString("Result");                             


            custs = (hometeam + "," + awayteam + "," + result);
            allResults.add(hometeamResults);
        }

    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error " +e);                                                                               
    }

    System.out.println("Size of HomeArrayList::"+allResults.size());
    for(HomeTeamResults temp:allResults){                                 

   if(temp.getResult().equals("W")){
       hometeamvalue = hometeamvalue + 50;
   }  

   else if(temp.getResult().equals("D")){
       hometeamvalue = hometeamvalue + 10;
   }

   else
   {           
           hometeamvalue = hometeamvalue + 0;           
    }

    }

}
```

And this is the code for the array

```
public class HomeTeamResults {   

private String hometeam;                                            
private String awayteam;                                
private String result;

public String getHomeTeam() {
return hometeam;
}

public void setHomeTeam(String hometeam) {
  this.hometeam = hometeam;
}

public String getAwayTeam() {
return awayteam;
}

public void setAwayTeam(String awayteam) {
  this.awayteam = awayteam;

public String getResult() {
return result;
}

public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
}

private  HomeTeamResults(String hometeam, String awayteam, String result) 
{
    this.hometeam = hometeam;
    this.awayteam = awayteam;
    this.result = result;

}

@Override
public String toString() 
{ 
    return " "+hometeam+", "+awayteam+", "+result; 
}
}
```

The problem I have is with the comparison. When I try if(temp.getResult().equals("W") then it doesn't work at all. And if I try if(result.equals("W") then what it does is take the first result from the array and then assumes that every other item in the array is the same.

Not sure where I'm going wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the object in the list but not initialize the object anywhere while iterating the result.

```
HomeTeamResults hometeamResults=null;  // Object is null
        while (rs.next()) 
        {               
            hometeam = rs.getString("HomeTeam");                      
            awayteam = rs.getString("AwayTeam");                   
            result = rs.getString("Result");                             
            custs = (hometeam + "," + awayteam + "," + result); // No idea abt usage
            hometeamResults = new HomeTeamResults(hometeam,awayteam,result); // Initial It
            allResults.add(hometeamResults);   // Now List will contain proper object
        }
```

Comment: updated the answer for more understanding.Your list will contain null object.

Comment: I see, so I shouldn't make the list null?

Comment: again updated the answer.Now what ever result you receive from db you will create the proper object and then set in the list

Answer (score 0):

You are initiallizing the reference with null value what you have to do first is to create your object then set the values in it somewhat like

```
 HomeTeamResults hometeamResults= null;
            while (rs.next()) 
            {     hometeamResults=new HomeTeamResults()
                hometeam = rs.getString("HomeTeam");                      
                awayteam = rs.getString("AwayTeam");                   
                result = rs.getString("Result");                             
                hometeamResults.setHomeTeam(hometeam);
                hometeamResults.setAwayTeam(awayteam);
                hometeamResults.setResult(result);
                allResults.add(hometeamResults);
            }
```

Comment: You are adding same object hometeamResults in the list.You need to initial it inside the loop